# Issue with Android Themes on different Activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I've got a little App, that should make use of the Systems default theme. However I've got two problems with that:

First thing is, on one Activity (TemplateView) Android does not apply the theme - or its really different from the rest of the app. Second, spinners an buttons on the ConfigurationView are not affected by the theme either.

I do not programmatically touch buttons and stuff. The only thing is the ArrayAdapter of the spinners, which use the andoird.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, which should also be themed if I'm not mistaken.

I've been trying to figure out, what is wrong here, but I can't seem to find it.

**My Manifest**

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme" >
        <activity
            android:name="de.isogon.discotalker.viewController.ConfigurationController" android:theme="@android:style/Theme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity><activity android:name="de.isogon.discotalker.viewController.TemplateController"></activity>
        <activity android:name="de.isogon.discotalker.viewController.AboutController"></activity>
        <activity android:name="de.isogon.discotalker.viewController.DisplayController"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**ConfigurationView** (Themes normally except for the Buttons/Spinners)

```
<de.isogon.discotalker.views.ConfigurationView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_configHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/label_configuration"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/actv_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_configHeader"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:dropDownHeight="wrap_content"
        android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint_text" >
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_start"
        android:layout_below="@+id/actv_text" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- Speed -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_speed"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/label_speed" />

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/sb_speed"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Size -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_size"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/label_size" />

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/sb_size"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Text Color -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_textColor"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/label_textcolor" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/sp_textcolor"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Text Backgroundcolor -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_textBackgroundColor"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/label_textbackgroundcolor" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/sp_textBackgroundcolor"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Backgroundcolor -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_backgroundcolor"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/label_backgroundcolor" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/sp_backgroundcolor"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Endless -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_endless"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/label_endless" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/cb_endless"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Vibrate/Sound -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_afterRun"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/label_afterRun" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/sp_afterRun"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_start"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_start" />

</de.isogon.discotalker.views.ConfigurationView>
```

**TemplateView** (Theme completly different - I've no clue why)

```
<de.isogon.discotalker.views.TemplateView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_templatesHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/label_templates"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         />

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/lv_templateList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_templatesHeader"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rl_containerButtons">

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/rl_containerButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn_edit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_edit"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_delete"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</de.isogon.discotalker.views.TemplateView>
```

Comment: Did you try changing themes in the manifest?

Comment: Yes, I've tried default (@android:style/Theme) and the light/black variants of it - although the look changed, both issues didn't change.

Comment: this could be due to this: de.isogon.discotalker.views

Comment: This is only a wrapper (extends RelativeLayout), which adds some easy setText(), onClick() etc. interfaces - nothing, that changes the appearance of the elements itself. So it should be themed I think.

Comment: try changing in res -> values :
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
 Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.

  <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was, that I used the getContext() method to inflate the first View and getApplicationContext() to infalte the other View.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem related to AppCompat v22.

The activities must extend the AppCompatActivity (instead of Activity) for the AppCompat theme (Material in my case) to be applied to them.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem using ArrayAdapter extentions for ListView - workaround here is to use MyActivity.this context instead of getApplicationContext() or getContext() methods.